How to fix SSL operation failed with code 1 when calling a script with CRON?
I'm trying to call a script localized on a o2switch server with a CRON from my website on a Gandhi server.
When I execute the CRON, I got the following errors :
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.gandhiwebsite.fr/htdocs/cron2.php on line 31
Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.gandhiwebsite/htdocs/cron2.php on line 31
Warning: file_get_contents(https://o2switchwebsite.com/exemple_php_api.php): failed to open stream: operation failed in /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.gandhiwebsite.com/htdocs/cron2.php on line 31
I checked the o2switch certificate that seems ok.
